# Is there a way to single out data within an SQL column?

Tags: sql, joomla

So I'm working with an old joomla site and trying to export only useful data, and I found a pretty hacky way of accomplishing what I wanted to do.

So for the column I want to get to, images, even though there's been no useful information input into it, joomla automatically populates it with the following:

```
{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

I Ideally only want to search for fields where the value for image_fulltext is not empty, and only get the value of the field.

My original idea was this hacky snippet just to find the relevant rows at least.

```
SELECT id, images FROM `JOOMLAPREFIX_content` WHERE images !='{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}'
```

This gets the me the relevant rows, but it also gets me more information than I want. (The first suggested solution, while a much less "hackey" query, gets me the same result, as you can see in the SQL snippet.)

```
Id          Images

7           {"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"images\/featuredimage1832014.jpg","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

Is there a way to target only the value of image_fulltext, in the case of this row: "images/featuredimage1832014.jpg"?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48075/1)

Comment: if I knew what the column data looked like perhaps then I could offer a way, otherwise look at text functions providing a "substring" for whatever the relevant database is. hints: tell use what the database is and provide an example of the data you want to target

Comment: Sorry, the column data is arranged like this:

`{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}`

Comment: Suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) The truth is we have no idea what is in those columns.  So you need to show us. Only then might we suggest a way to get to "single out" what you want

Comment: Sorry for not posting an adequate MCVE the first time around. I tried to explain my problem better and replicated the database in an SQL fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, images FROM `JOOMLAPREFIX_content` WHERE images NOT LIKE '%"image_fulltext":""%'
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, Thank you so much! That gets me the correct rows in a much more appealing way :) Is there a way to only output the value of image_fulltext? `"image_fulltext":"VALUE"`